# Forcing version of library B to match transitive dependency of library A

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management

If I include CXF 3.3.6 in a project

```
implementation(group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty', version: "3.3.6")
```

Using the dependencies task we see that it will also bring in `jetty-server:9.4.27.v20200227`

```
+--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty:3.3.6
|    +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:3.3.6 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:3.3.6 (*)
|    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:9.4.27.v20200227
```

Now i would like to add jetty-servlet to project also:

```
implementation(group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-servlet', version: 'XYZ!?!')
```

Is there a convenient way to force the `jetty-servlet` dependency to match the version of the transitive dependency of `jetty-server` brought in by CXF?

Answer (score 0):

If the dependencies will have the same version, then you can use a custom [dependency resolution rule](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/resolution_rules.html#sec:custom_versioning_scheme):

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'org.eclipse.jetty') {
            details.useVersion "9.4.27.v20200227"
            details.because "Align all Eclipse Jetty dependencies to same version"
        }
    }
}
```